# How to break down allocated memory into several regions and assign process?

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management

I understand how to allocate 'one big piece' of memory by using

```
int shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, int size, IPC_CREAT | 0666)
```

However, how can I break down this one memory region into many regions?
For example,

```
[          heap           ]
[region1][region2][region3]
```

Then, I believe within each forked process I have to use

```
int shmget(key_t shmid, 0, 0666)
```

to access a region I guess?..

I also see the term 'offset' a lot of online sites related to memory allocation... what does it mean?..

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is it technical in nature, like "what function do I use to ___?" or is it algorithmic in nature, like "How do I know that a region in my shared memory has been allocated or freed?"

Comment: Well my questions was more of, what function to use. I did not know how to let multiple processes allocate & free memory section at the same time. For example, process 1 allocating memory to region1, process 2 freeing the memory at region 2(was already allocated). After more search, I now belive I have to use shmget once and then use **void* shmat(int shmid, (void *) 0, 0)** number of times to break down a heap into multiple regions...

Comment: now by using **void* shmat(int shmid, (void *) 0, 0)**, instead of **(void *) 0** if i give specific address to map and if it gives -1 then ill know that it failed mapping the memory section, which means there is some memory already allocated in that space...... right?

Answer (score 0):

on a modern linux system there is not much reason to use `shmget` & Co. Use `shm_open` together with `mmap`, instead. The interface is much easier to use.

I didn't understand if you wanted to partition your map voluntary or if it was just a consequence of what you read about `shmget`. But with `mmap` you can easily just map parts of the region, if you want to.